Difference in meaning לָתֶת vs. לִתֵּן
Before the early Sh'ma in Brachot, we say the paragraph beginning with (from the Sefaria Ashkenazic davening)

לְפִיכָךְ אֲנַֽחְנוּ חַיָּבִים לְהוֹדוֹת לְךָ וּלְשַׁבֵּחֲךָ וּלְפָאֶרְךָ וּלְבָרֵךְ וּלְקַדֵּשׁ וְלָֽתֶת־שֶֽׁבַח וְהוֹדָיָה לִשְׁמֶֽךָ:

some of my siddurim don't have the bolded word, but instead have what Sefaria has for Sefardic davening:

לְפִיכָךְ אֲנַֽחְנוּ חַיָּבִים לְהוֹדוֹת לְךָ וּלְשַׁבֵּחֲךָ וּלְפָאֶרְךָ וּלְבָרֵךְ וּלְקַדֵּשׁ וְלִתֵּן שֶֽׁבַח וְהוֹדָיָה לִשְׁמֶֽךָ:

but my siddurim have a mix of which word is used, regardless of being Askhenazic siddurim.
What might the difference be in meaning between the two (I would have thought the word was "v'lAtein")? What are the grammatical rules or textual precedents that would call for one over the other?

ולתת is Biblical Hebrew; ולתן is more the Rabbinic form. There's a wide-ranging debate, going back a couple of centuries (see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31691/18471 for one example), about how much (if at all) the wording in the siddur should be modified to follow Biblical Hebrew.

Slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73467/15256

According to the Academia of Hebrew Language for the verb נתן - give, the Biblical Hebrew and modern Ivrit form is לָתֵת. One can find this form in Bereshis 15:7, Devarim 10:18, Devarim 17:15 and many other places. It is also found in Aleinu prayer: לָתֵת גְּדֻלָּה לְיוֹצֵר בְּרֵאשִׁית.
The form לִיתֵן is Mishnaic Hebrew. It is found in Pirkei Avot 3:1, Bereshis Rabba 1:10 and other rabbinic texts.
